# Release references at end of script

Tags: javascript, regex, variables, null, photoshop-script

I'm sure this has been asked but here goes:

In Photoshop using JavaScript is it best to release references to variables at the end of a script

```
// Release references
results = null;
srcDoc = null;
x = null;
```

Without an IDE do I then need to write another script to find all references to

> var foo = bar;

so I can list them and then release them from the initial script?
Something like this in regex

```
/(var\s+)(.+)(\s+=\s+)(.+);?/gim
```

Comment: you don't need to "release references" - JS engines are smart

Answer (score 2):

When you assign a variable the value `null` what you're doing is clearing the reference to the data so that it will be eligible for garbage collection. If no other variable in the JavasSript code has a reference to the same data, then it can be freed by the garbage collector. If there is another reference to the data then it will not be freed.

When variables go out of scope or their parent object is deleted then they are eligible for garbage collection.

You don't have to manually remove references in your code, assigning the variable to `null` is sufficient.